# Bash processes - reattach process started in background

Tags: linux, bash, process

Is there a way to reattach to a specific terminal a process that was started from terminal with &?
For instance, I started Kate by:

```
kate &
```

and now I want to reattach the process to a given terminal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1) Death by HUP and avoiding that:

If you start a program in a shell and then end that shell then all child processes will be killed. This includes programs running in to background. (Those which you start with an & at the end of the command, like the `kate &` in your example, but also processes which you suspended with <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> and then `bg`).

Both will die once you close the shell.<sup>*1</sup>

You can work around this by `disown`ing the backgrounded program. It will then keep running, but you can no longer get it back to the foreground of a shell.

You can use nohup (e.g. `nohup kate &`) to keep the output from the program in a file. But full reattachment to a shell is also no longer possible.

2) Terminal emulators.

You can also start a program which emulates a terminal on its own and which is specially build so you can reconnect to it. `screen` and `tmux` are two examples of this.

Example of screen usage:

- log in or ssh to host.
- `screen`  (starts screen. By default this starts a new shell).
- `kate` (starts kate).
- <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (Detaches the screen, you will be back at the same prompt you had when you logged in for the first time.).
- `logout`

Walk to another computer, or come back hours later. (or both :))
 - log in or ssh to host.
 - `screen -r`  (Reattach screen. you are now back at a shell where you are running kate.

Useful commands for screen:

screen -d
Detach a screen from outside the screen program.
Use Control<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to detach from inside screen.

screen -r 
Reconnect to the screen (e.g. from a different location)

screen -dr
If there is an attached screen, then first detach it. Then attach it locally.
Useful of you forgot to detach it at the office and log in from home ;)

screen -x
Attach to a running screen without closing the other session. Useful for shared debugging, help session etc. etc.

---

<sup>*1</sup>: Edit:
When I answered this I assumed that all shells would always sends a sigHUP to all of its children. However this is an option and depending on the shells it may be configurable. In some cases it even is no longer the default.

Example1: In bash you can configure this option via the buildin command [shopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html). (`shopt -s huponexit`).

Example2: With zsh you want [`setopt`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html)`HUP`.

Comment: fg solves my problem only if I didn't close the parent terminal. However, if I close the parent terminal I won't be able to reattach my process to it. Maybe I haven't explained well my question.

Comment: That is why you first start `screen`. You can then start the program (without using the `&` to background it. You can detach (sort of close) the screen with control-A-D and the program will keep running.  The next morning you can log in and use `screen -r` to reattach and you will be back at the program. You can even log in from home (e.g. via SSH) and reattach the screen.

Answer (score 26):

[`fg`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/1posix/fg/) brings something from the background to the foreground in the current terminal.

Comment: But that won't work if I close the parent terminal.

Comment: @Mauren, ah, I didn't quite understand your question. Hennes has the correct answer. Look into using [Tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I didn't know `fg` could do that. This worked for me with a simple backgrounded task by `bg` or `prog &`. Thanks.