# Running ZIP Process in Background in CentOS

Tags: terminal, centos, connection, zip

How can I run the following command/process in background immediately after starting it:

```
zip -r file.zip directory/*
```

What I actually want to do, is to run the `zip` process working even after exiting / disconnecting from the terminal - just like the `-b` option in `wget`

Comment: zip -r file.zip directory/* &

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I actually want to do, is to run the zip process working even after
>   exiting/disconnecting from the terminal

Let me ignore the 'zip' part.

To continue to run **any** program after disconnecting from the terminal, either:

1. Run in the background and `disown`.
2. Use TMUX
3. Use [screen](https://superuser.com/questions/644537/bash-processes-reattach-process-started-in-background).

Comment: What if I just put the process in background by adding an `&` at the end of the command `(zip -r file.zip directory/ &)` and then `exit` the terminal without `disown`?

Comment: If you do that (or fire it up and then use <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>`bg %1`) then it might get killed when you exit the shell. Might since this is an option which can be set in the shell. E.g. see  [shopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html). (`shopt -s huponexit`) for bash and  [`setopt`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html)`HUP` for zsh).

Answer (score 1):

To run process in background you need to add `nohup` at the end of process and end it with `&`
so the command will be like this

```
nohup zip -r file.zip directory/* &
```

and to see the running process in background run this command

```
jobs
```